# Suma de una lisita string con diferentes valores

Tags: python

Después de varias ediciones empezamos de cero. Estoy aprendiendo Python poco a poco de manera autodidacta.
Estoy intentando desarrollar el juego de las 7 y media con dos jugadores .

Ya he desarrollado el código que genera la baraja, pero no se como continuar para realizar la suma del valor de las cartas. Cada carta tiene su mismo valor excepto de las figuras que valen 0.5.ç
Por ejemplo si tengo un cuatro de oros y un k de copas en la lista jug1 = [], necesito crear una variable que me devuelva el valor, en este caso 4,50. El código que llevo es el siguiente.

```
import random

valor = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","J","Q","K"]
color = ["espadas","copas","oros","bastos"]
baraja = []

for v in valor:
    for c in color:
    carta = "{}  de  {}".format(v,c)
    baraja.append(carta)
random.shuffle(baraja)        
print(baraja)

jug = []
jug1 = []

jug.extend([baraja.pop(), baraja.pop()])
jug1.extend([baraja.pop(), baraja.pop()])   

print("Tus cartas son: " , jug,"    Quieres otra carta?")

opcion = input("Escriba SI o NO:    ")

while opcion == "SI":
    jug.extend([baraja.pop()])
    print("Tus cartas son: " , jug,"    Quieres otra carta?")
    opcion = input("Quieres otra carta? Escriba SI o NO:    ")

else:

    #realizar la suma y comparar entre jugadores
```

Respecto a alguna respuestas, no es ninguna  tarea/trabajo . Simplemente estoy  acabando una ingeniería electrónica y me gustaría aprender machine learning, por eso estoy empezando por Python, únicamente tengo formación de una asignatura en 2º que dimos algo de Java.

Se aceptan recomendaciones para seguir una hoja de ruta y aprender de manera autodidacta.

Gracias y saludos

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses un [diccionario](https://docs.python.org/es/3.10/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=dictionary#dictionaries) para saber el valor de cada carta y que iteres sobre los arrays que representan las manos de los jugadores para sumar todos los elementos. Si agregas código se te puede ayudar de una mejor manera. Lastimosamente creo que ponerte una respuesta con código puede ir en contra del propósito del sitio y que simplemente no se aprenda ni se obtenga nada y que funcione como un lugar donde la gente puede tener código gratis para sus tareas/trabajos.

Answer (score 0):

yo tambien soy nuevo pero creo que tengo una respuesta para ti, si a todas las cartas las llamas por el numero primero y despues por el palo, podrias recortar el nombre y convertirlo en un numero
ejemplo:

```
carta="1 de bastos"
carta=carta[:carta.find(" ")]
#como ves le digo que lea solo hasta el primer espacio, solo leera el numero
carta=int(carta)
```

esa es mi solucion para los numeros, para las letras no se me ocurre nada aun pero volvere por aqui cuando se me ocurra, tengo ganas de ver lo que programes si me lo permites